# Почему вывод в консоль (двух переменных и функции подряд) одинаковый?

Tags: c++, консоль

```
std::bitset<8> b(1);
std::cout << b << std::endl << b.flip(1) << std::endl << b;
```

Почему вывод на консоль после этих инструкций

```
00000011  
00000011  
00000011
```

, а не

```
00000001
00000011
00000011
```

?

Comment: У меня разный: 00000001, 00000011.

Comment: Вы можете проверить, проблема в выводе или в методе `flip`? Это бы сузило вопрос.

Comment: О,  а теперь иной взгляд на вопрос. Мы-то думали, flip у вас не сработал, а нет, как раз наоборот. Видимо, в вашем компиляторе этот код преобразовался к такому виду, что сначала выполнились вычисления, а потом только пошёл вывод. Кстати, имя компилятора в студию, пожалуйста.

Comment: @AivanF. `GCC 4.9.2`

Comment: Складывается ощущение, что здесь просто нет точек следования, вследствие чего, порядок вычисления аргументов `<<` не указан явно.

Comment: В `g++.real (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4` тот же результат, а вот если вывод разбить на 3 части, то все ожидаемо (первый 01, остальные 11)

Comment: @StateItPrimitive похоже на то, на хабре подобные примеры есть

Comment: @anton_s Да, но странно то, что во всех тестируемых компиляторах результат совпадает (вряд ли во всех них одинаковый порядок обработки аргументов с отсутствием точек следования). Хм, учитывая этот факт, начинает складываться новое впечатление того, что на самом деле множественный вызов оператора `<<` преобразуется в единичный вызов оператора `<<` с множеством параметров, а это уже явная точка следования (вызовом функции является точкой следования), т.е. точка следования гарантирует, что все аргументы будут вычислены до вызова функции.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, но ведь flip - тоже функция?

Comment: @Qwertiy Да, но она будет являться точкой следования лишь для вычисления своих аргументов, но не более (например, `f() + g()` - перед вызовом каждой из функций имеется точка следования, которая гарантирует, что её аргументы будут посчитаны до её вызова, но в тоже время оператор `+` не является точкой следования, а следовательно порядок вызова функций `f` и `g` неуточнен). Но это все уже не важно, т.к. _Flowneee_ уже дал хорошее обоснование, да и в моем предположении о множестве параметров все равно есть изьяны (там надо все параметры передавать по ссылке, чтобы значения получились одинаковые)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

В C++ порядок вычисления аргументов функции не определен ([Стандарт](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) С++ секция 5.2.2/8).
Вы можете думать о конструкции (опустим `<< std::endl << b;` для краткости)

```
std::cout << b << std::endl << b.flip(1);
```

как о:

```
std::operator<<(std::operator<<(std::cout, b), b.flip(1));
```

Очевидно, что, исходя из стандарта, ничто не мешает компилятору сначала посчитать `b.flip(1)`. Соответственно, возникает *неопределенное поведение* (так как ближайшая *точка следования* находится при вызове функции, после вычисления ее аргументов).

P.S. Вот [хорошая статья](http://alenacpp.blogspot.com/2005/11/sequence-points.html) на тему точек следования.

Comment: Понятия 'точка следования' не существует начиная с 'c++11'.

Comment: @alexolut Но, фактически, закрепленное за этим понятием поведение компилятора остается прежним (понятие упразднили, но по факту ничего не изменилось, ну или по крайней мере я не знаю, что именно изменилось :D). Все операции всё-равно делятся на гарантирующие последовательность выполнения определённых действий и не гарантирующие. Т.е. понятие «точка следования» заменили на два: «операция последовательна» или «операция не последовательна» (аля _rename_?).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Поведение осталось, но описание этого поведения стало опираться на математическое понятие "отношение". Короче говоря, стало лучше, проще и однозначнее. Если ещё не читали, вот [ответ на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4183735/3240681)

Answer (score 2):

В онлайн компиляторах разных версий плюсов (вроде [ideone](https://ideone.com) и [C++ Shell](http://cpp.sh)) вывод такой же, как у Вас. Похоже, это не исключение, а норма. Возможно, это прописано в спецификации В целом же, использование в одной строке нескольких разных значений одной переменной грозит *неопределённостью* ([cppreference.com](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order)).